# How to properly compile and link against C program?

Tags: c++, c, makefile

I have a logger that I wrote in C, and have included it in a C++ project I am working on.  It works fine, but I get a deprecated warning from Clang++: "Treating C input as C++ when in C++ mode, this behaviour is deprecated."

In hopes of doing away with this warning, I moved the compilation of the logger into its own step in the make file and compiled the object file with Clang.  Then I added a reference to that object file to my Clang++ rule to link against.  Now it fails to link properly: "Linker command failed with exit code 1"

My makefile is below.  How would I properly go about compiling and linking this C logger so as to do away with that warning in Clang++?

```
CC= clang++
PROG= ./bin/tetris
OBJS= ./src/main.o ./src/Tetris.o ./src/states/BaseState.o ./src/states/MenuState.o \
    ./src/states/GameState.o ./src/entities/Block.o ./src/entities/Tetromino.o \
    ./src/entities/Grid.o
LIBS= allegro-5.0 allegro_dialog-5.0 allegro_font-5.0 allegro_ttf-5.0 allegro_color-5.0 \
    allegro_primitives-5.0 allegro_main-5.0 allegro_image-5.0 allegro_audio-5.0 allegro_memfile-5.0
CXXFLAGS= -g -Wall -std=c++11 $(shell pkg-config --cflags ${LIBS})
LDFLAGS= $(shell pkg-config --static --libs ${LIBS})

all: logger $(PROG)

$(PROG): $(OBJS)
    mkdir -p ./bin
    $(CC) -v -o $(PROG) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJS) ./src/util/SimpleLogger/simplog.o
    rm -f $(OBJS)

logger:
    clang -c -Wall ./src/util/SimpleLogger/simplog.c -o ./src/util/SimpleLogger/simplog.o

clean:
    rm -f $(PROG) $(OBJS)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may not be what you are looking for, but you could include it in your C++ file by:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

// C code

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Comment: The plan is to be able to use this logger in C and/or C++ projects alike. This doesn't quite look like it would help me meet that goal...

Comment: @PseudoPsyche This is *exactly* how you make a header C **and** C++ compatible.

Comment: @PseudoPsyche Also, in your header file, write `CXX = clang++` and `CC = clang`. Don't compile C code with a C++ compiler.

Comment: Okay, I changed over to `CXX = clang++` and `CC = clang` in my makefile.  But now it doesn't build...Getting an error for `string.h` in `atomicity.h`  `"error: use of undeclared identifier '__ATOMIC_ACQ_REL'"`  When I just had `CC = clang++`, all of my object files were compiling with g++ due to implicit rule there.

Comment: Okay, as far as the compilation issue, I need to leave it as `CC = clang++` because clang 3.0 doesn't have support for atomics apparently. That's why it is falling back on g++ when compiling those object files.

Comment: As far as the compiling the C code for linking, that did it!  Thanks!  Sorry for my noobishness getting in the way initially...  For future reference, does that method of wrapping the C header file have a name?

Comment: @PseudoPsyche It is a standard trick in C++ header files that must also be C compatible, if you want you can probably call it an "extern C guard" to make the point.